# Why does Windows FSRM always use a contoso email address?

Tags: windows, admin, quota

When File Server Resource Manager sends a quota email to an end-user, it seems always to use `storage.quota@contoso.com` as the `From:` address, rather than the address specified in the FSRM Options.

The GUI shows the correct `From:` address.

Checking `Get-FSRMSetting` shows the correct `FromEmailaddress`

There's nothing extra in the quota template.

...yet the mail always comes from `storage.quota@contoso.com`